# (If possible ) How to merge this "right angle shaped" cell in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

This grid is inserted as a table.

Looking at the right angled shape below.
[image]

How to I merge these two cells together?

[image]

When selected, there is no option to merge them?
Basically, I just trying to "draw" this shape.

EDIT:

My current solution is to edit each of the cell boarder lines separately, and make it invisible. Just wondering if this is an easier way.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to do that in my opinion. In HTML you can only span rows or columns not together. So Word does the same. But you can do a trick. Place a L shape onto the table and put your text into it.

Comment: The problem is that it's "too" complicated to draw the L shape that fits like this.